# How to format a Unix timestamp in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have

```
var timestamp: Longint;  
timestamp := Round((Now() - 25569.0 {Unix start date in Delphi terms} ) * 86400);
```

which I am using as a primary key in some MySql stuff.

But I would also like to format the date/time, like [PHP's date() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) does.

Does anyone have a code snippet or URL?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You are looking for

```
function DateTimeToUnix(const AValue: TDateTime): Int64;
```

and

```
function UnixToDateTime(const AValue: Int64): TDateTime;
```

functions from DateUtils.pas

TDateTime value can be formatted by **[FormatDateTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/FormatDateTime_%28Delphi%29)** function

Comment: how to get output in millisecond?!

Answer (score 24):

This is much faster

```
// 4x faster than dateutils version
function UNIXTimeToDateTimeFAST(UnixTime: LongWord): TDateTime;
begin
Result := (UnixTime / 86400) + 25569;
end;

// 10x faster than dateutils version
function DateTimeToUNIXTimeFAST(DelphiTime : TDateTime): LongWord;
begin
Result := Round((DelphiTime - 25569) * 86400);
end;
```

Comment: +1 thanks. I don't do it too often, but this is useful to know

Comment: Note that DateTimeToUNIXTimeFAST has a slight difference from the DateUtils version, if milliseconds = 500..999, DateUtils will round backwards, while FAST version will round up towards the next second.

Comment: Result := Trunc((DelphiTime - 25569) * 86400);

Comment: Including `SysUtils` unit you could write the same as `(UnixTime / SecsPerDay) + UnixDateDelta` and `Round((DelphiTime - UnixDateDelta) * SecsPerDay)`.

Answer (score 7):

I would use `DateTimeToUnix`, as suggested by @kludg.

```
function DateTimeToUnix(const AValue: TDateTime): Int64;
```

In case you want the current Unix timestamp in **milliseconds** format, you can implement the following function:

```
function UNIXTimeInMilliseconds: Int64;
var
  DateTime: TDateTime;
  SystemTime: TSystemTime;
begin
  GetSystemTime(SystemTime);
  DateTime := SysUtils.EncodeDate(SystemTime.wYear, SystemTime.wMonth, SystemTime.wDay) +
        SysUtils.EncodeTime(SystemTime.wHour, SystemTime.wMinute, SystemTime.wSecond, SystemTime.wMilliseconds);
  Result := DateUtils.MilliSecondsBetween(DateTime, UnixDateDelta);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned function UNIXTimeToDateTimeFAST should use Int64 and not Longword. For older dates (negative values) Longword gives wrong results.