# Why do I get a result many thousands of years in the future when I call UnixToDateTime?

Tags: delphi, unix, datetime, time, timestamp

I have the following timestamp: `1444288186967`.

When I put that in a [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/#tools), I get correctly **08 Oct 2015 07:09:46** as result.

However, when I use (as mentioned in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420188/how-to-format-a-unix-timestamp-in-delphi)) the `function UnixToDateTime(const AValue: Int64): TDateTime` I get **02 Sep 47737 11:02:47**. Strange, isn't it?

My code (using TMS Aurelius)

```
Person.EndDate.Value := UnixToDateTime(FHit.TimestampUntil);
```

Where `FHit.TimestampUntil` is an `Int64` as the `UnixToDateTime` function expects.

The `Person.EndDate.Value` is a TMS Aurelius nullable `TDateTime`.

How is it possible that I get such date as result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally Unix timestamps are in seconds since 1.1.1970. However, the value `1444288186967` is in milliseconds. Divide by 1000 and round and you will get the expected date and time 8.10.2015 7:09:47

```
  i64 := round(1444288186967/1000);
  dt := UnixToDateTime(i64);
  Edit2.Text := DateTimeToStr(dt);
```

Edit2 shows 8.10.2015 7:09:47

Comment: The [`UnixToDateTime()` documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.UnixToDateTime) says: "*Unix date-and-time values are encoded as the number of **seconds** since midnight at the start of January 1, 1970*", and the [Epoch Convertor](http://www.epochconverter.com/#tools) says "*Assuming that this timestamp is in **milliseconds**.*" for `1444288186967`.